# Бывает ли слово "по-любому" вводным?

Tags: синтаксис

Бывает ли слово "по-любому" вводным?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Надо еще доказать, что это слово уже вошло в литературный язык.

Ладно, будем считать, что вошло. И означает оно приблизительно "в любом случае". Если так, то оно не может быть вводным.